# Detect left mouse button down after sending left mouse button up

Tags: c++, windows

I am writing a program that scans if the Left Mouse Button is held down, then sends a left mouse button up and continues after that. The problem is, since I am sending a left mouse button up, the program will not continue because the left mouse button is not being held down anymore.

Here is some pseudo:

```
if(GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0){
   Sleep(10);
   mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, p.x, p.y, 0, 0);
   //Rest of code
}
```

How can I detect the left mouse button being down after this? Would I have to use a driver?

Comment: _"the program will not continue because the left mouse button is not being held down anymore"_ I don't follow.

Comment: It is still being held down on the physical mouse, I was wondering how I could detect the physical mouse button being held down.

Comment: Don't send `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP`.

Comment: It's part of what I'm doing. I need to send it.

Comment: For what reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading your description of the program only here is my implementation.
Using the Windows API:

```
while (true) {
     //check if left mouse button is down
     if (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000) {
         //send left mouse button up
         //You might want to place a delay in here
         //to simulate the natural speed of a mouse click
         //Sleep(140);

         INPUT    Input = { 0 };
         ::ZeroMemory(&Input, sizeof(INPUT));
         Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
         Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
         ::SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));
     }
}
```

You can place this code into a function that you call in a thread if you want to do other things while you forcibly stop people from clicking and dragging.

```
void noHoldingAllowed() {
     //insert code here used above...
 }

 int main(void) {
  std::thread t1(noHoldingAllowed);
  //other stuff...

  return 0;
{
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a flag:

```
bool lButtonWasDown=flase;

if(GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0){
   Sleep(10);
   lButtonWasDown = true;
   mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, p.x, p.y, 0, 0);
} 

if (lButtonWasDown)
{
  // rest of the code for lButtonWasDown = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but it should work

```
while(programIsRunning)
{
   if(GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0){
   Sleep(10);
   mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, p.x, p.y, 0, 0);
   // rest of the code
}
```

It should work since if you have the Lmouse button held while the loop reruns if will trigger the if statement which will then trigger a mouseup event.

note:
You might be able to do `while(GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0){//code here}`

Comment: The `if(GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0)` is already in a `while(1)` loop. I tried the `while(GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0)` and that did not work, did the same as an if statement.

Comment: What do you do with the mouseUp event?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I just want to send mouseUp and still have the rest of the if statement running.